# Github: mute notifications for PR or user

Tags: github, notifications, pull-request

It is possible to mute notifications on specific pull requests but leave notifications on for the project as a whole?

Or to mute notifications from a specific user?

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question, The answer is yes: You can disable notifications on a particular PR by clicking on the `Unwatch` button above that PR. However, you will still receive notifications for the project as a whole if you are `watch`ing the project page.

Comment: I see "Unwatch" and "Unsubscribe" on the PR page. Both appear to be global (project) in nature. Haven't tested, as I need notifications for every other PR, but there's 1 user generating a sh*t load of notifications on a single PR that I don't want to see.